# Change Encryption Method in Java Application Using Pdfbox

Tags: java, encryption, pdfbox

I am researching changing the encryption method used in a java application that uses PdfBox.  The change is from SHA1withRSA to a more secure method.  Specifically I am looking for the encryption methods supported by PdfBox.  Alternatively if there is information that shows that PdfBox does not handle the encryption but passes the parameters needed to Adobe Reader for it to do the encryption.

Comment: `SHA1withRSA` sounds like a digital *signature* algorithm (which by chance internally uses encryption). PDFBox does support the current PDF *encryption* schemes, like revision 6 AES256 encryption, and also the older schemes, like revision 2 RC4 encryption, and it does support modern digital *signature* algorithms.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @mlk Thank you for pointing out the difference in digital signature and encryption.  It is a signature.  This was not clear to anyone on my team and it was assumed to be a form of encryption of the PDF as a whole.  If I understand then, java creates the signature object and that is what PDFBox adds to the PDF?  It would be almost similar to what it does for a jpeg or other information?